Expected no. of coin tosses to get two consecutive heads for the first time and Fibonacci series
Consider the experiment that you toss a coin until you get two consecutive heads appear for the first time. Now the question is, what is the expected no. of tosses needed to get this?
This question was asked in GATE 2015 and most of the solutions I found are given as, first calculating the probabilities p{X=2},p{X=3},p{X=4},.. (where X is the random variable assigned) i.e.,
p{X=2} = $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ for {H,H}
p{X=3} = $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ for {T,H,H}
p{X=4} = $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ for {T,T,H,H}..  and so on
finally the expectation is
E[X] = $2*(\frac{1}{2})^2+3*(\frac{1}{2})^3+4*(\frac{1}{2})^4+... = 1.5$
the problem I found was with the probabilities
p{X=2} = $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ for {H,H}
p{X=3} = $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ for {T,H,H},  upto here its fine, but
p{X=4} = $2*(\frac{1}{2})^4$ as $2^4$ is the total permutations for four tosses and in them ({T,T,H,H},{H,T,H,H}) are the favourable outcomes
similarly,  p{X=5} = $3*(\frac{1}{2})^5$ ;  p{X=6} = $5*(\frac{1}{2})^6$
panning out we can see the probabilities has a fibonacci sequence i.e.,
{$\frac{1}{2^2};\frac{1}{2^3};\frac{2}{2^4};\frac{3}{2^5};\frac{5}{2^6};\frac{8}{2^7}$;... }, so
E[X] = $2*\frac{1}{2^2}+3*\frac{1}{2^3}+4*\frac{2}{2^4}+...$
Now in calculating this I tried to get it into a summation form, which is my first doubt, how to write the fibonacci series in a summation form which will result
E[X] = $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n*(some~f(n))}{2^n}$ or maybe some other fraction entirely
Secondly does this series converge? I tried it with the brut force calculation of upto  27 terms, although contribution from higher terms reduces the sum seems to be growing from above the third decimal(by the way the sum was around 5.482, whereas compared to the 1.5 the previous procedure gives).
Or am I wrong with the solution part in the first place, I would appreciate some enlightenment on this. Thank you.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Don't use $*$ for multiplication. Prefer \cdot so, $2\cdot\frac1{2^2},$ if you don't want to write $\frac2{2^2}.$

It's not "some $f(n),$" it is just $f(n).$ Look up the "generating function for the Fibonacci numbers." It converges because $\frac12<\left|\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right|.$

I suggest that you read the last portion of Robert Israel's answer very carefully.  His approach, in this portion of his answer, really makes the problem trivial.

Yes, it's true that $\mathbb P(X = n) = F_{n-1}/2^n$ for $n \ge 2$, where $F_n$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number, so
$$ \mathbb E[X] = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n \frac{F_{n-1}}{2^n} $$
Convergence is easy because $F_n \sim \phi^n/\sqrt{5}$ as $n \to \infty$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. You could compute the sum using Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers.  But it's easier to do it this way.  Let $x$ be the expected number of additional tosses to get two consecutive heads given your last toss was H, $y$ the expected number given your last toss was T.  Then by considering the possibilities for the next toss, we get
$$ \eqalign{x &= 1 + y/2\cr y &= 1 + x/2 + y/2\cr}$$
Solve...
[EDIT] To elaborate on this.  Let $x$ be the expected number of additional coin-tosses to get two consecutive heads, given that you have just tossed H (but have not yet had two consecutive heads), and $y$ the expected number of additional coin-tosses to get two consecutive heads, given that you have just tossed T.
Consider first the case where you have just tossed H. Since you're not done, you must make another toss. The result is equally likely to be H or T. If it is H, that makes two consecutive heads and you're done.  On the other hand, if your next toss is T, you are back in the situation of "last toss T".
So $$x = 1 + \frac{1}{2} y$$
Next the case where you have just tossed T.  Again, you must make another toss. This toss will take you either to "last toss H" or "last toss T", with equal probability. So
$$ y = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y $$
At the start of the experiment, you are in basically the same situation as "last toss T".  So $\mathbb E[X] = y$.

Thank you for the Fibonacci part, I get it now. But could you elaborate the second part I couldn't quite get it .
